# Change all pixels that lie in a given color range to a new color

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

This is what I have so far but it's not perfect... Any input would be very helpful!

```
def picture_reset_pixels(filename, from_color, to_color, target_color):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    pixels = list(img.getdata()) 
    red_list=[]
    for i in pixels: 
        R= i[0]
        G=i[1] 
        B=i[2] 

        if R >= from_color[0] and R<= to_color[0] and G >=from_color[1] 
                and G<= to_color[1] and B >= from_color[2] and B<= 
                to_color[2]:
                    red_list.append(target_color)
        else:
            red_list.append((round(R),round(G),round(B))) 

    red_image = Image.new(img.mode,img.size)
    red_image.putdata(red_list) 
    return red_image
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is split over three lines, in a way that I think is not valid in Python. If you put brackets around it, then you can break it up across lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253348/very-long-if-statement-in-python

Comment: Also clarify what `import`s apply. What are `Image` and `round`?

Comment: @200_success round is a built-in function. For the Image my guess is it comes from pillow.

Comment: This question is lacking context. What are the used imports and what is the code supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

## Improving the general implementation

Generally we want to avoid `append`ing to a list too many times if we can help it. This is because lists are dynamic arrays, so `appends` can be unnecessarily expensive (though the *dynamic* part helps with the efficiency). Instead, when we know the size of the input set (i.e. the number of pixels in the image), we can take advantage of that information. But in this case, that will be unnecessary because `Image` provides us with some handy helper methods to handle this very situation:

```
from PIL import Image

def picture_reset_pixels(filename, from_color, to_color, target_color):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    pixels = img.load()
    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        for j in range(img.size[1]):
            if all(from_color[k] <= pixels[i, j][k] <= to_color[k] for k in range(3)):
                pixels[i, j] = target_color + (255,)
    return img
```

Assigning `pixels` to `img.load()` allows us to take advantage of directly editing the image. Since copying the image into another list was unnecessary originally (to clarify, the `img` variable doesn't affect the file on disk that `img` originated from, i.e. the file at location `filename`), editing directly is the best way.

**Edit 2:** Looking at it again, I think @Reinderien's point about clarity has merit because `range` has an exclusive upper bound, which may be confusing because it is asymmetric relative to both of its arguments. I have edited to use the comparison operators `<=` and `>=` instead of the `range` check I mention ahead. The caveat only I have is that using the `in range` form is more similar to how I think a dedicated `ColorRange` object (mentioned ahead in the section **Going beyond the current form**) should handle a range check, since it's not necessary to expose the object's implementation details (though internally, it could still use comparison operators for the check).

Another general improvement I've taken advantage of in this implementation is using `range` to check if each of the RGB values of a pixel are between the two pixel boundaries of the input arguments. [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all) serves the purpose that the `and` statements in the original version served: it requires that all the pixels compared in the iterator `pixels[i, j][k] in range(from_color[k], to_color[k] + 1) for k in range(3)` are in the required range for the condition to be true.

**Edit 1:** the concern was raised in comments that testing for `in range(from_color[k], to_color[k] + 1)` would be extremely inefficient. However, this is mistaken and arises from a misunderstanding of how Python 3.x implement the `range` object. Checking if a number is in a `range` is a constant time operation. I would recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081318/8117067) to understand Python 3.x's range implementation.

## Going beyond the current form

While I've shown you a way to use your current parameter requirements in a more efficient implementation, I think there are some improvements you can make so `picture_reset_pixels` has more functionality. I think combining `from_color`, `to_color`, and `target_color` into a single dict parameter `color_replacements` could make this more versatile (where the key-value pairs would derive something like `{(from_color, to_color): target_color}`; you could even create a custom `ColorRange` class to encapsulate the idea of a range of colors).

There's also another issue I find with your current implementation: it can only support certain image types. I tried your algorithm on a `GIF` file and it failed because the pixels in a `GIF` file are ints, not four-tuples like `PNG`s. You also do not support the fourth alpha channel of PNG, because your pixel range bounds are only 3-tuples. You might want to consider investigating that further if you want to support multiple image types.

Comment: @Reinderien That would be true if this were Python 2.x. But in Python 3.x, `range` is the equivalent of Python 2.x's `xrange` and returns an iterator. [Python 3.x also added an optimization for the `.__contains__()` method so that it is O(1) time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081318/8117067).

Comment: It smells, to me. Using a pair of inequalities is simpler, and no less legible.

Comment: @Reinderien Looking at it again, I think I agree with you. The exclusive upper bound of `range` can be a bit confusing. And Python does have this neat interval comparison where `A <= X and X <= B` can be written as `A <= X <= B` so it's not redundant and synonymous to its math form. The caveat only I have is that using the `in range` form is more similar to how I think a dedicated `ColorRange` object should handle a range check, since it's not necessary to expose the object's implementation details (though internally, it could still use comparison operators for the check).

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are manipulating the image one pixel at once. Instead you can work on the whole array as one when using the `numpy` interface:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def read_image(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    return np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")

def write_image(img, image_path):
    img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img, dtype="uint8"), "RGBA")
    img.save(image_path)

def picture_reset_pixels(img, from_color, to_color, target_color):
    mask = (img >= from_color).all(axis=-1) & (img <= to_color).all(axis=-1)
    img[mask] = target_color

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from_color = (100, 100, 100, 255)
    to_color = (150, 150, 150, 255)
    target_color = (0, 0, 0, 255)
    filename = "test.png"
    img = read_image(filename)
    picture_reset_pixels(img, from_color, to_color, target_color)
    write_image(img, filename)
```

Note that I chose not to return the modified image since the function modifies it inplace. If you want to avoid that, just add `img = img.copy()` as the first line and add `return img` at the end.

Also note that this assumes that your image has an alpha channel. If not you need to change `"RGBA"` to `"RGB"` and of course have the colours be only three-tuples.

Answer (score 1):

The code is overall simple and good but could be improved in a few things that would make it a bit shorter and more readable

---

Inside the `for` loop, in the `if` / `else`, you are repeating `append` in both of your cases. You could do instead

```
to_add = (round(R), round(G), round(B))
if condition:
    to_add = target_color
red_list.append(to_add)
```

---

On the condition, you can also refactor using chained comparison to improve readability, preferably in ascending order. If you break that line, do so aligning conditionals as follow :

```
if from_color[0] <= R <= to_color[0] and \
   from_color[1] <= G <= to_color[1] and \
   from_color[2] <= B <= to_color[2]:
```

Alternatively, but sightly less explicit, you can iterate over i.

```
if all((from_color[j] <= i[j] <= to_color[j] for j in range(3)))
```

---

R, G, B initialisation can be made a single line:

```
R, G, B = i
```

or, if working with a 4 tuples:

```
R, G, B, _ = i
```